# Directive does not trigger output changes in the DOM on click event unless I scroll

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For some random reason I create a directive that triggers on click, but when the click event is detected, the directive does not execute unless I scroll on the page, otherwise the directive won't fire itself.
This bug only happens on windows, not on mac.
Both work on the same version of Chrome (55)

Here is a sample of a simple directive that will fire on windows only after a scroll

```
app.directive("myDirective", function(){
    return{
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            element.click(function(){
                alert("clicked");
            })
        }
    }
})
```

Please do not comment it's an error of syntax as Im not really familiar with stackoverflow code edition, the code works well on mac, and other machines. I just encounter a random lag on some windows machine (not all) if anyone has ever encountered the same issue please

Comment: This should work, so probably something else is causing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use non-angular events inside your directive you need to tell Angular about the change in its digest-apply cycle. In your case it appears that scrolling triggers a new event and angular will apply the changes made in the previous click event which weren't applied since it wasn't aware of.

The easiest way to fix this is to use `scope.$apply` which will tell angular to apply your changes to its model (and hence, the DOM)

```
app.directive("myDirective", function(){
    return{
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            element.click(function(){
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    alert("clicked");
                });
            });
        }
  }
})
```

This might sometimes give you an error (inprogr) in case you call an apply while there's an apply already in progress. I suggest you to use the `$timeout` service, which will safely apply changes as soon as possible (after the current apply has ended)

```
app.directive("myDirective", ['$timeout', function($timeout){
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      element.click(function(){
        $timeout(function() {
          alert("clicked");
        });
      });
    }
  }
}])
```

For more about this topic: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog

And here's a plunkr showing the problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/QGSlbK?p=preview (the inprog error will not happen in this simple example but might happen in more complicated cases)